# Escape c# class property from JSON serialization (to remove quotes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, highcharts

**I EDITED THE SOLUTION BELOW THE QUESTION !!!**

---

I have read like 30 similar articles on this, but nothing quite hits the spot.

My scenario: in order to feed a charting library (highcharts/highstock) with data in ASP.NET I  manually created the basic classes for such a graph. This is due to the fact that all the wrapper projects work for highcharts but NOT for highstock. However, highstock requires a HTML script block like this (working):

```
<script>
$('#container2').highcharts('StockChart',
{
"title": {
    "text": "Graph_Title_string"
},
"yAxis": {
    "title": {
        "text": "YAxis_Title_string"
    },
    "height": 200,
    "lineWidth": 2,
    "top": 80
},
"series": [
  {
      "type": "line",
      "name": "Testdata",
      "data": [[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0), 3], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 9, 0, 0), 2], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 10, 0, 0), 4], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 11, 0, 0), 4], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 12, 0, 0), 3], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 13, 0, 0), 4], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 14, 0, 0), 2], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 15, 0, 0), 1], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 16, 0, 0), 4], [Date.UTC(2014, 3, 17, 0, 0), 0]]
  }]
});
```

I created the c# classes and their properties, as for example:

```
public class Series
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }    
}
```

Later on I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize my chart-object (with instanced classes title, yAxis, series etc within), which results in following output:

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Graph_Title_string"
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "YAxis_Title_string"
    },
    "height": 200,
    "lineWidth": 2,
    "top": 0
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "name": "Testdata",
      "data": "[[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0), 3],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 9, 0, 0), 2],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 10, 0, 0), 0],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 11, 0, 0), 4],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 12, 0, 0), 4],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 13, 0, 0), 2],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 14, 0, 0), 1],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 15, 0, 0), 1],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 16, 0, 0), 0],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 17, 0, 0), 3]]"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the problem is: the value of series->data is enclosed in quotes. As highstock obviously requires an object array as data ([[DateTime, value],[DateTime, value],...etc]), the chart is not rendered unless I remove these quotes around the array.

When the array was "pure" integer there would be no quotes (I guess), but as my points need to be DateTime/value I need an array of objects.

Therefore the question: **how can I force my JSON serializer to NOT enclose my value of an object array in quotes?**

Maybe this is trivial and simple, and I was looking to far. As said, I've read lots of articles on similar problems, but nothing worked for me. Any help highly appreciated!

---

**SOLUTION**:

the data-array in my series-node is int/double - DATE.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0) doesn't return a DateTime but a NUMBER (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Therefore defining a double array in my behind-class will result in the desired output format (as seen in the great suggestion below by craig and also the marked answer) without the quotation marks.

Code (reference: http://forums.asp.net/post/1463013.aspx ... however, slightly modified) for converting c# DateTime to the required milliseconds-timestamp:

```
public double MilliTimeStamp(DateTime d2)
        {
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);

            return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

Comment: what is the actual type of object referenced by `data` property?

Comment: This is a bit messy: it is a string.

Explanation for that: somehow the HIGHSTOCK API is only able to read DateTime from `Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0)` in the resulting <script>-block. Therefore I fill my data-member with a prepared string with date-value-pairs exactly as required in the <script>-block. 

So right now the string stored in _data_ looks like this: [[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0), 3],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 16, 0, 0), 0],[Date.UTC(2014, 3, 17, 0, 0), 3]]

What I tried before: object[DateTime,double] ... which still puts the DateTime in quotation marks.

Comment: are you sure the problem is quotation marks around each DateTime? I mean, isn't it no.1 that caused the problem : 1."[[DateTime,0]]" instead of 2. [["DateTime",0]]. If you really need this format : [[DateTime,0]] it is not a valid JSON, you'll need a custom serializer to achieve that

Comment: Good point - I watched my array a little bit closer again. Obviously the java method for Date.now() returns an integer number, so Date.UTC(Y-M-D) returns an integer number, not DateTime. Therefore my data-object has to be numerical.

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s93Kn/1/
A converter for dates: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm (use the unformatted result)

That works, and once I have a double-array to serialize no evil quotes will come and ruin my party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @CraigW. is very close. To make it closer to what you are after, try to declare `data` as collection of collection of object :

```
public class Series
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}
```

Test code to populate the model :

```
Series series = new Series();
series.type = "foo";
series.name = "bar";

series.data = new List<List<object>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var data = new List<object>();
    data.Add(DateTime.Now);
    data.Add(i);
    series.data.Add(data);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series, Formatting.Indented);
```

Test result :

```
{
  "type": "foo",
  "name": "bar",
  "data": [
    [
      "2014-04-17T22:15:06.8812404+07:00",
      0
    ],
    [
      "2014-04-17T22:15:06.8812404+07:00",
      1
    ],
    [
      "2014-04-17T22:15:06.8812404+07:00",
      2
    ],
    [
      "2014-04-17T22:15:06.8812404+07:00",
      3
    ],
    [
      "2014-04-17T22:15:06.8812404+07:00",
      4
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble really understanding his root problem, but I think it's the fact that the DateTime types have quotes around them that is the current problem.

Comment: While this produces exactly the STRUCTURE I require, the initial problem remains: the quotation marks around the DateTime objects in the JSON result are my problem.

Any way to remove these while serializing? As said in a comment above, the HIGHSTOCK api seems to require EXACTLY Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0) - without quotation marks.

Thanks so far, this is already helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I created a class defined as follows:

```
public class Series
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }    
}
```

Then used the following code to populate it and convert it to JSON.

```
Series series = new Series();
series.type = "foo";
series.name = "bar";

series.data = new List<object>();

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    series.data.Add( DateTime.Now );
    series.data.Add( i );
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( series );
```

The resulting JSON was:

> {"type":"foo","name":"bar","data":["2014-04-17T07:47:16.3620755-07:00",0,"2014-0
>   4-17T07:47:16.3620755-07:00",1,"2014-04-17T07:47:16.3620755-07:00",2,"2014-04-17
>   T07:47:16.3620755-07:00",3,"2014-04-17T07:47:16.3620755-07:00",4]}

P.S. Declare `data` as `object[]` also generated the above JSON.

Comment: Probably they will, but my data array/list can't be of type DateTime, since I need to enter two types as data points (DateTime, int/double). So it has to be public object data (or public object[] data, which makes no difference)

Comment: Okay, I didn't catch that in the original question. I updated the answer with some code and the results I got from trying this myself.

Comment: Maybe much clearer than my inital question because so straight forward. You can see what's bothering me: having the quotation marks around the DateTime-parts of the JSON output causes the HIGHSTOCK library to fail.

What I further tried: Date.parse("2014-04-17T07:47:16.3620755-07:00") instead of Date.UTC(2014, 3, 8, 0, 0) in the resulting <script>-block. However, no luck there either.